# in AD can we give admin access to a particular installed application

Tags: administrator, active-directory, group-policy, privileges

In AD can we give admin access to a particular installed application.i dont want to give the admin privilege to the user

for example i have installed visual studio if we are not giving the admin rights then it won't update the license and the required DLL files

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but you should assume that if the user can use one program as admin, they have **full admin access.** For example, VisualStudio includes a tab to run arbitrary commands; aside from the obvious fact that it allows the user to run custom software which he writes himself.

Answer (score 0):

There is only the third-party tool Runasrob you can configure particular software or contents of whole folders to run as administrator from a limited user account.

http://www.robotronic.de/runasadminen.html

Easy to use and helpful for a lot of things.